# How to evaluate this definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals, symbolic-computation

I want to obtain the symbollic expression for this integral:

$\int^\infty_{-\infty} \, dx \, \left(\frac{y - x}{R^2 + (y-x)^2}\right)\, e^{-\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{4 s^2} - \frac{i k (y - x)^2}{2 R}}$,

where $i$ is the imaginary unit and **all** other variables are real. With symbolic, I just want to make clear that the answer should maintain the form of all the variables, but $x$ in the final form of the result.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to simplify the form of the equation to the maximum in order to expose to others. It's a good exercise and more people will be willing to help.

Comment: Sorry the lower limit was meant to be minus infinity.

Comment: i think there is no solution in elementary functions